# Android Studio 3.0 Preview Missing Imports when refactoring Kotlin code

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Whenever I try to refactor Koltin code on Android Studio 3.0 it simply removes all my "top level" imports and starts using "inplace" imports.

By refactoring I mean, in this case, moving code around. So let's say I have a class under **com.myapp** package. If I move it to **com.myapp.anotherpackage** this issue happens

**Funny fact about this looks like it only happens when you move more than one file at the same time**

What it looks like:

```
//Before refactoring I have this import
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //code
}
```

Then after refactoring it goes like this

```
//"top level" import is gone

class MyActivity : android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity() { //"inline" import
    //code
}
```

[image]

It gets even worse if I have to refactor the code again, as every single import is "inlined", the android studio doesn't refactor those, and I have to do fix them by hand. This is getting really annoying already, as I had to fix over 100 of these. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "refactor"? Which specific refactoring did you use?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Just to make sure everything is clear, I added an image of what happened just now

Comment: Just delete the package reference(i.e highlight yellow)in for each access class. You should get the top level imports automatically.

Comment: Yeah, but I have to do that manually all the time, and this feature works perfectly with Java, there has to be a way for it to work with koltin

Comment: Looks like you should be reporting a bug, rather than asking a question.  Did you report this to the issue tracker (probably Jetbrains YouTrack)?

Comment: Are u using Refactor > Move ?

Comment: As of AS 3.0 Canary 2, I can not reproduce this. Your AS version is the same as mine ?

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to bug which was fixed not long ago. The relevant changes weren't included to the Kotlin plugin bundled with a As3.0 preview yet. But they will be available in the next plugin update.

Comment: Aleksei have "Kotlin Developer at JetBrains" in his profile :)

Comment: Well, it's not fixed because I still have this exact problem on the latest release as well :/

Answer (score 1):

Tad late to join the party, but, anyway. Kotlin is a relatively newer language (in terms of it being official for Android, hardly a month ago), so development is at full pace at JetBrains. And, the Android Studio version(3.0) is not a stable release, so here are all the known issues of Kotlin with Android Studio. Check these issues [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/kotlin-issues.html).

There it clearly says:

> **Some refactorings not available with Kotlin**
>
> Not all code refactorings works with Kotlin, especially those for Android. For example, code refactoring to modularize Kotlin cude currently does not work with Kotlin.

The Java friendly Android Studio is not acquainted with the inline functionalities of Kotlin. Since, this is a new inclusion in Kotlin, it makes code more readable (really?) but not so *programmer-friendly*, per se.

Having said that, right now there is hardly any source (checked a few, others are welcome) confirming that your problem is an *issue* or an improvement of Kotlin over Java (again highly debatable) since `inline`-ing was meant to be an improved functionality.

Now, it's about time that this *feature* is addressed to with an ***official*** tag.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be a bug - I managed to recreate the issue in IntelliJ and created this bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18205

Comment: This is fixed with version 1.1.3 of the Kotlin plugin.

Comment: Nope I still experience this on `1.1.3-2`

Comment: @PärNilsAmsen I've just tried it myself, and the issue in the YouTrack ticket is fixed in Kotlin plugin 1.1.3-release-IJ2017.2-2. I use IntelliJ, so I'm not sure when the fix will make it into Android Studio. Maybe the issue you are experiencing is subtly different (did you try the steps in the ticket)? Have you got some steps to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this "refactoring" happens after the file was moved and the package updated.

As a workaround until the IDE / Plugin bug gets fixed you can do the following:

After moving your file (refactoring) right click the file,

1. Select Local History → Show History
2. Select the previous revision where it removed all the imports
3. Select revert

Make sure to double check the result, you know should have the properly moved/refactored version.

---

Occasionally this does not seem to work, but you can then try to Undo (Move) and move it again.

*Tested on AS 3.0 Canary 3*